# Subtract from column the value of the first column that is not NA while going back through the data.frame

Tags: r

I've got a dataset with variables of the cumulative time spent on filling out a websurvey (every variable corresponds to one page of the survey). I need the variables to display not the cumulative time, but the time spent only on that page. Unfortunately, as there are filters in the questionnaire, some variables have `NA` due to pages being filtered.

Here's some sample data (the first variable can be considered as a baseline and does not include any `NA`):

```
   rts5032939 rts5032955 rts5032973 rts5032974 rts5032975 rts5032977 rts5032978 rts5032979 rts5033085 rts5033089
1          70         99         NA        104        111        119        132        147        175        196
3          33        144         NA        156        165         NA        199        259        297        357
15         18         57         NA         63         69         80         99        174        190        221
20       2107       2126         NA       2131       2139       2209       2220       2236         NA       2274
24       1088       1111         NA       1117       1124       1133       1152         NA       1208       1228
30         27         61         NA         70         83         90        182        230        298        336
```

Here's a dput() for you to work with:

```
test <- structure(list(rts5032939 = c(70, 33, 18, 2107, 1088, 27), rts5032955 = c(99, 
144, 57, 2126, 1111, 61), rts5032973 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), rts5032974 = c(104, 
156, 63, 2131, 1117, 70), rts5032975 = c(111, 165, 69, 2139, 
1124, 83), rts5032977 = c(119, NA_real_, 80, 2209, 1133, 90), rts5032978 = c(132, 
199, 99, 2220, 1152, 182), rts5032979 = c(147, 259, 174, 2236, 
NA_real_, 230), rts5033085 = c(175, 297, 190, NA_real_, 1208, 298), rts5033089 = c(196, 
357, 221, 2274, 1228, 336)), .Names = c("rts5032939", "rts5032955", 
"rts5032973", "rts5032974", "rts5032975", "rts5032977", "rts5032978", 
"rts5032979", "rts5033085", "rts5033089"), row.names = c(1L, 
3L, 15L, 20L, 24L, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

The expected output looks like this. Note that the variables don't have to be replaced, I'm perfectly fine with newly generated variables.

```
   rts5032939 rts5032955 rts5032973 rts5032974 rts5032975 rts5032977 rts5032978 rts5032979 rts5033085 rts5033089
1          70         29         NA          5          7          8         13         15         28         21
3          33        111         NA         12          9         NA         34         60         38         60
15         18         39         NA          6          6         11         19         75         16         31
20       2107         19         NA          5          8         70         11         16         NA         38
24       1088         23         NA          6          7          9         19         NA         56         20
30         27         34         NA          9         13          7         92         48         68         38
```

Before I noticed the problem with the `NA`, I used

```
for (i in 2:10) {
  df1[paste0("t_", i)] <- df1[i]-df1[i-1]
}
```

to generate new variables with the subtracted time. Obviously, this does not work when sometimes a `NA`-value will be used.

Considering that the `NA` happens case-by-case, the new approach has to loop through the columns **and** the rows. To be honest, I'm not even sure how to begin here. Can anyone point me to the direction on how this can be achieved? I'd be happy with a general advice from which on I could do the specifics myself.

**Edit: To clarify, I need the output to be only the difference between the value and the value of the first not-`NA`-value that comes before in that row.**

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: I've edited the expected output into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is better but will definitely be slow!

```
abc <- function(x){
  zz = as.numeric(x)
  w <- 0
  for (i in 1:length(zz)){
    if (i==1){
      w[i] = 0
    } else {
      w[i] <- zz[i] - zz[max(which(!is.na(zz)[1:i-1]))]
    }  
  }
  return(w)
}

t(apply(test, 1, abc))
```

---

Got the solution using a faster approach (using apply()) - Let me know how this performs in terms of speed

```
abc <- function(x){
  y = x[!is.na(x)] # get those non -NA values
  x[!is.na(x)] = c(y[1], diff(y)) # find the diff() of non NA ones and replace them to their original spot
  return(x)
}

t(apply(test, 1, abc))
```

Comment: yu know, we can have a iterative process but will be damn slow!! I shall try that

Comment: Sweet, that does it! Many thanks for your effort! Minor thing: It kills the baseline variable (all 0), but I can just reinsert the original, so it doesn't really matter.